# wget mirror rss website

Tags: wget, mirror

I want to use wget to get a mirror from one RSS site, and want to mirror all the links of 3 level deep

```
wget -m -k -l 3  http://www.cnn.com/services/rss/
```

However, in the output, I only see the index.html and terms.html. Is there any special with RSS site or I can not mirror this site please?

Thanks in advance.